# How to update gitlab from a not-git repository??6.0 to 6.5

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When i install gitlab on my server first time, i can't git clone the repository from github.com(There is something in China called GREAT FIRE WALL, you know...).Then I　download the zip file, and I unzip and install it successfully on my server.
Now, I want to update my 6.0-version gitlab. Referring to the official doc of [Gitlab From 6.0 to 6.5](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-6.5.md),  i can't do git command absolutely.
I think I may do this:

> 1. backup my config files
> 2. rename my old gitlab directory
> 3. download zip file, or git clone gitlab repository (thanks GFW) to where my old gitlab directory is
> 4. follow [Gitlab From 6.0 to 6.5](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.0-to-6.5.md), and ignore all git commands

What did i miss????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed [**`gitlabhq/gitlab-shell`**](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell), which you need to upgrade as well, which means you need to download its zip.

See [`gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/releases`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/releases).